# ruby on rails: received email confirmation link doesnt work with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid, email-confirmation

I am a total newbie on programming and I tried to program email-confirmation with ruby on rails in development mode. I followed a tutorial for registration with email confirmation and they used sendgrid, an addon for heroku. I made an account there and installed everything.

Now here is the problem: When signing up and getting the email with the confirmation link, if I open the link this comes out on a new website (http://myapp.herokuapp.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=n6RmknbFU5G_uH4NrSZ1 )
Application Offline for Maintenance
This application is undergoing maintenance right now. Please check back later.

[image]

So I cannot sign up. Where is the problem? What can I do?

in my user.db I wrote this:

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
end
```

in config/environments/developement.db I added this:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.herokuapp.com' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

in initializers/setup_mail.rb I wrote:
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => 'redacted@heroku.com',   
    :password => 'redacted',
    :domain => 'https://mysterious-forest-46337.herokuapp.com/',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: I forgot to tell you, I use MySQL2 as database in my ruby&rail program. But heroku uses postgres.  Maybe this cannot work?

Comment: What's the link to your app?

Comment: Hey Richard, I already resolved the problem. You are right, it was the link in the app which was wrong..